# Extend column color to bottom of page using Bootstrap rows containers and columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, styling

I can't seem to be able to extend the color of a bootstrap col to the bottom of the page. I don't want to set a fixed height, I want it to extend to the bottom of the browser screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col box1">
      Box1
      I need the blue to extend to bottom of page
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Box2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
.box1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

JS Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/romanbogza/oL3nk8wz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min-vh-100` ( min-height: 100vh; ) class for that.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col box1 min-vh-100 bg-info">
            Box1 I need the blue to extend to bottom of page
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Box2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```